# How to wrap @KafkaListener for custom method arguments?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use case in which I want to pass extra method arguments to my kafka consumer method.

Something like :

```
@KafkaListener(
        id = "TestService",
        topics = "testTpoc",
        groupId = "kafkaGroupId1",
        autoStartup = "true")
    public void receiveTestEventWithContext(final CustomContext customContext, final ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) {
        log.info("Recieved kafka message with custom context");
    }
```

Is there any way that I can pass CustomContext to my consumer method?
I have a use case in which I want to pass this context to some downstream API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@KafkaListener` method is called from a thread which loops over `KafkaConsumer.poll()`. All the arguments for that method are really fed from that scope. Since there is nothing Kafka-related in your `CustomContext`, then there is no way to pass it from the listener container. And technically it must not since this custom object just does not make sense for Kafka consumer scope.

Well, you can do that with custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. See `KafkaListenerConfigurer` to implement. And then `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.setCustomMethodArgumentResolvers(HandlerMethodArgumentResolver... methodArgumentResolvers)`. But is this exactly what you are looking for? Cannot you just create that `CustomContext` in this `receiveTestEventWithContext()` method and pass it down as you wish when Kafka record is received and handled by this method?

Comment: Thank for your answer.

Yes, I could do it inside `receiveTestEventWithContext()` method if it was for a single instance.
We have my own flavor of spring boot starter, which is used by many of our service developers. We want to setup logging context, tracing context etc. using this CustomContext object. This way our service developers will have a way to pass it for downstream calls (if any). CustomContext is supposed to hold this information.
I did found a way to pass it by making use of RecordMessageConvertor and copying all kafka headers into Context and create a wrapped object.

Comment: But your solution works better, we could introduce this as a non-breaking change for our users. Thank you! :)